# Add query string variables to all hyperlinks URL matching a specified domain

Tags: plugin-development, query

This is my case. Supposing in my plugin dB table I have the following stored field name and values:

```
argument_1= 'test'
argument_2= 'test2'
```

And I want to add a new string query string variables to all links going out to www.example.com such that it will look like this:

If homepage is accessed:

```
www.example.com/?argument_1=test&argument_2=test2
```

Or any page like this:

```
www.example.com/anotherpage/?argument_1=test&argument_2=test2
```

What Wordpress hooks, actions and filters would I be using to retrieve the arguments and values in the database and append it to a hyperlink URL if it matched the domain, e.g. example.com ?

I am thinking of using add query arg but I'm confused a bit on how this function relates to this application. Any tips and advices are highly appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: What are the `arguments`? Meta_data, dates, tags? This is important on how to call them in `the_loop` but you may want to check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query and php's `$_GET[]`

Comment: No, they are not meta_data, dates or tags. They are pure values stored in a custom wordpress database table, not in post meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I read your question wrong. You probably want to use [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) and do something like:

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(argument_1=test&argument_2=test2)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(argument_1=test&argument_2=test2)$'] = 'index.php?argument_1=$matches[1]&argument_2=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
}
```

this is untested and mostly stright from the docs but should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks Bandon :).So if I view the URL in the sourcecode, it will now be rewritten like this? www.example.com/anotherpage/?argument_1=test&argument_2=test2 or it will still display the original URL but it will only be redirected to this new URL? I am not familiar with wp_rewrite.

Comment: That particular rule will require something like anotherpage/?argument=1&argument=2(although i forgot the & in the code) you could also do `anotherpage/1/2` then rewrite it to have your args if you desired.

Comment: Does this require .htaccess to be modified? It is not clear in the docs.

Comment: if you use the filters above, no. If you don't want to use filters then yes (see example 2 in docs) It's either filters or `.htaccess` but really no need for both. If you want to talk more I created this chatroom: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7180/wpse-82459